# How to change timeslider step in CartoDB/torque?

Tags: carto, timeslider, torque

I am using CartoDB and I have a torque map that I am using for a course.  The visualization only covers three months of time.  I would like the timeslider to show each day, but right now it shows every two days.  I have tried manipulating the duration and steps, but without success.  As a non-programmer, is there any why for me get the visualization and timeslider to display every day rather than every two days?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please use descriptive titles for your questions.

Answer (score 2):

All you should have to do is go to the time slider options.  Change the Time Step interval to 1.0 and change it to Days.  Time window should also be 1.0 days as well.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I have not been able to locate the time slider options.  Could you be more specific? Thanks

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005z0000000z000000